# Is it risky to truncate a table during a Rails DB migration?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm adding a migration that is adding a unique index to a MySQL table.  Is there any real risk in truncating any existing data in the table so the unique index can be added, given that existing data in the table may not be unique?

It's important to mention that this app is still in development and has not yet been released to production, and therefore we would not be losing any real user data.

Can anyone come up with a real-world scenario in which we might lose important data down the line?

Code example of the migration:

```
class AddUniqueIndexToFooOnBarAndBaz < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE foo")
    add_index :foo, [:bar_id, :baz_id], unique: true
  end

  def down
    remove_index :foo, [:bar_id, :baz_id]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr- you won't hurt anything really, but don't do that TRUNCATE anyway.  Do a `db:reset`**

What happens when you write a migration is that the `db/schema.rb` file gets changed and its version is set to the timestamp on the last migration that was run.  The migration files exists so that:

1. You can have concrete files which demonstrate the changes to the database over time, using a DSL which makes sense.
2. You can rollback the changes to your database semi-arbitrarily, if you discover something is wrong during development (don't rollback your production DB, just write a new migration)

This means that migration files should show what you're doing to the database and that TRUNCATE isn't really what you're doing to the DB, it's what you're doing to the *data*.  It won't break anything and that SQL snippet won't run if you deploy a new environment using a schema that's already migrated, but for any environment that's already up, it will.  That's just kinda weird and definitely unnecessary.

**The Details**

What happens when you deploy your app for the first time in an environment is you (should) run `rake db:create db:schema:load db:seed` or `rake db:setup` (which just farms out to the other commands).  `db:schema:load` simply converts your `schema.rb` file into an actual database schema, with tables and indices and all that fun stuff.  After you've run your migration, your schema file **will have the index you want**.  Then, whenever you deploy to production, your database will look like you want it to out of the box, before any data is added.

In development, you shouldn't be attached to any data that's in your database- it's test data, unimportant and ephemeral.  You shouldn't feel bad wiping it all out, especially if you're truncating because the existing data might be invalid/duplicated.

Comment: My goal in the truncate was to not have to reset the entire db so as to minimize the impact of running this migration for other devs on my team.  So just wiping this one table felt right to get the migration to most easily pass.  Would you be inclined to agree that the truncate would fit in this case?  Or do you have a more "surgical" alternative to the db:reset that isn't a truncate?

Comment: What you're doing isn't application logic, it's operational.  So it shouldn't be persisted in your application (i.e. get written into a migration).  Just hop into SQL or rails console (`Model.destroy_all`) to do it.

Comment: Perhaps, but there are more than a few examples of people (Google for 'rails data migration') using Rails migrations for more than just changing the DB structure - i.e. migrating/altering data, either pre/post the change in DB structure..

Comment: Not arguing that you can't do it, just that you shouldn't.  It would be one thing if your app was already in production and you had to use a migration to manage the data as well as the DB, but since you're still in dev, it's going to mislead anybody who reads that migration down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Truncating a table has consequences whether you use a rails migration or not.   The better question is to ask whether it's risky to truncate the table, period.

Since you're not in production, there is no risk of impacting "real" people, but what you have to consider is how will truncating the table impact your data integrity and how as a developer, will you recover from any issues you may encounter.

For example, if the data you're truncating is in a join table connecting two other tables, then you've lost the relationship between your two tables and you've basically rendered a significant chunk of your data useless.  However, if the data is in an insignificant table, then the impact is a lot lower.

In short, yes, there are risks, but the best person to answer the level of this risk is you.

Comment: Interesting point about the data integrity of the overall DB that I hadn't considered.  In this case, it is not a join table, and there are no foreign keys pointing to this table.